# get the decode value of QR code using Appium and postman

Tags: python, automation, postman, appium, genymotion

I have created a session and located the QR code element ID using endpoint mentioned in [Appium documentation](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/text/).
[image]

This is the value of text I'm getting from QR code; I expect the actual decode of QR code which can be further used in applications for automation. I was wondering if other application needs to be used or it is possible in postman itself.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved by using python's cv2 library

```
filename = "img.png"
# read the QRCODE image
image = cv2.imread(filename)
# initialize the cv2 QRCode detector
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
# detect and decode
data, vertices_array, binary_qrcode = detector.detectAndDecode(image)
if vertices_array is not None:
print("QRCode data:")
print(data)
else:
    print("There was some error")
```

Comment: you might need to use "condo"

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact, there are several questions here, is the QR code value static or dynamic, that is, does the QR code change during each test or can you use the same QR for all tests

If the value does not change(static), you can create a file, say .yaml, in the *resources* or *test data directory*, where your value will be stored in an encoded form, then you read this value from the file, decode it and pass it to the test script

If the QR code changes(dynamic value) for each test, you can create an API call, *for python you can use the requests library or Java RestAssured*, you take the encoded value from the response, decode it and pass it to the test script

the implementation depends on the above, but the whole process must be implemented within your framework

So you don't need to use additional tools like Postman etc to get value and decode it, if you want to automate your case properly combine API and UI

To decode value in Python I use *Fernet*, Java *bouncycastle*

Comment: thanks for the effort, I did used Fernet to decode the static QR code, but it resulted in something else, just to clarify I need data when scanned the payment QR code, The UPI ID will typically be in the format "upi://pay?pa=[UPI ID]".

Comment: In general, there are two ways how to automate this case, I'm a little confused with your description of the case. I don't understand which one you want to use.

Comment: If you only want to use Appium and UI part without API, the steps are: 1. Take a screen shot off a QR screenshotBase64 = self.driver.get_screenshot_as_base64(). 2 Read file and decode it: from **pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
decocdeQR = decode(Image.open('qr.png'))**
print(decocdeQR[0].data.decode('ascii'))

Comment: Java implementation but you can extend logic https://github.com/eliasnogueira/appium-read-qrcode/blob/33c305c23457272955e9a8a8979e74619ceb36e2/src/test/java/com/eliasnogueira/qrcode/ReadQRCodeTest.java#L134

Comment: How to decode QR from image https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2022/01/18/decode-a-qr-code-using-python/#:~:text=For%20decoding%20QR%20codes%20using,pip%20install%20pillow

Comment: thanks for responding, it was useful though I found the solution